# how to append lat long received from gps to url?

Tags: java, android, string

I get the latitude and longitude info in my android app.I put them as double. I am able to display it through toast.

Now I wish to append that lat-long into my URL so that I can make a http get request.

This is how i have to append the lat and long info

http:/localhost:8080/search/ByLatLngRadius?lat=38.87705&lng=-77.31462&radius=20

Need help!!

Comment: Umm, convert them to a string and append them with string concatenation?  What's the problem?

Comment: @GabeSechan I am able to do that. But I need to pass these values in the middle. after the"=" symbol. I do not know how to put the lat long values after the "=" symbol.

Comment: Make the string out of multiple parts.  "http:/localhost:8080/search/ByLatLngRadius?lat=" + latitude + "&lng=" + longitude + "&radius=20"

Comment: @GabeSechan I have an error. the string gets appended. But the value of the double when converted to string becomes zero. How do I take the same value?

Comment: @user2208748 check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string builder and append values as below

```
StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();       
urlString.append("http:/localhost:8080/search/ByLatLngRadius?lat=");

urlString.append( latitude); 
// use this if latitude is double
//   urlString.append( Double.toString(latitude));
urlString.append("&lng=");
//  Double.toString(longitude)
urlString.append( longitude);
urlString.append("&radius=");
urlString.append(radius);
```

Comment: The lines urlString.append( latitude);  and urlString.append( Double.toString(latitude)); both convert the value to zero. I do not get the actual value of lat and long.

Comment: check if you actual value ie double latitude is null or not

Comment: I am getting the proper value in my toast. I am using the same value in the string builder. But when I check the value for lat and lng individually, it is zero. I am appending the lat lng value after I call the location listener method.

Comment: the lat lng value were limited to the method. Its values could not accessed outside. Now I am getting the proper value.

Comment: declare you lati and longi variables with class scope. Should be available for the entire class

Comment: I tried it with both public and private. Even then I am not able to access it in my onCreate.

Comment: it should if your doing it right. Once declared with a class scope it is accessible through out the class.

Comment: I am not able to paste the whole code here as I have a limit to the number of characters.

Comment: i can't help you anymore in that case.